# Create Nested Array DataFrame From Existing DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to create a nested struct array column from a dataframe during a 'join' operation in scala. The only thing I appear to be able to get working is setting up a array of elements structure which does not look write in the json output.

The current schema I am starting with is:

```
root
 |-- memberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberSubscriberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberIdSuffix: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberLastName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberFirstName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberMiddleInitial: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberSocialSecurityNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberGender: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberBirthDate: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphonenumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphoneextensionnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- membercellphone: string (nullable = false)

root
 |-- memberSubscriberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- subscriberaddresstypecode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- lineOne: string (nullable = false)
 |-- lineTwo: string (nullable = false)
 |-- lineThree: string (nullable = false)
 |-- cityName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- stateCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- zipCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- countyCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- countryCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- subscriberphonenumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- subscriberphoneextensionnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- subscriberfaxnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- subscriberfaxextensionnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- address: string (nullable = false)
```

Going to I think:

```
root
 |-- memberSubscriberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberIdSuffix: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberLastName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberFirstName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberMiddleInitial: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberSocialSecurityNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberGender: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberBirthDate: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphonenumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphoneextensionnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- membercellphone: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberAddresses: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lineOne: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lineTwo: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lineThree: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- cityName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- stateCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- zipCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- countyCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memeberPhoneNumbers: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- phoneNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- effectiveDate: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- terminationDate: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isCurrent: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isActive: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- telecomType: string (nullable = false)
```

Current code:

```scala
val clientDF: DataFrame
val addrDF: DataFrame

import spark.implicits._

    val nestedAddr = addrDF.select(
      $"clientSubscriberId",
      array(
        struct(
          $"lineOne",
          $"lineTwo",
          $"lineThree",
          $"cityName",
          $"stateCode",
          $"zipCode",
          $"countyCode",
          $"countryCode"
        )
      ).as("clientAddresses"),
      array(
        struct(
          $"subscriberphonenumber".alias("phoneNumber"),
          //$"subscriberphoneextensionnumber"
          lit(null).alias("effectiveDate"),
          lit(null).alias("terminationDate"),
          lit(null).alias("isCurrent"),
          lit(null).alias("isActive"),
          lit("home").alias("telecomType")
        ),
        struct(
          $"subscriberfaxnumber".alias("phoneNumber"),
          //$"subscriberfaxextensionnumber".map(c => col(c).as("phoneNumber"))
          lit(null).alias("effectiveDate"),
          lit(null).alias("terminationDate"),
          lit(null).alias("isCurrent"),
          lit(null).alias("isActive"),
          lit("fax").alias("telecomType")
        )
      ).as("memeberPhoneNumbers")
    )
    val addrMbrDF = mbrDF.join(nestedAddr, Seq("clientSubscriberId"))
```

Resulting schema:

```
root
 |-- memberSubscriberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberIdSuffix: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberLastName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberFirstName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberMiddleInitial: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberSocialSecurityNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberGender: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberBirthDate: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphonenumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphoneextensionnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- membercellphone: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberAddresses: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- lineOne: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- lineTwo: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- lineThree: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- cityName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- stateCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- zipCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- countyCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memeberPhoneNumbers: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- phoneNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- effectiveDate: null (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- terminationDate: null (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isCurrent: null (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isActive: null (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- telecomType: string (nullable = false)


Expected schema:
root
 |-- memberSubscriberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberIdSuffix: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memberLastName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberFirstName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberMiddleInitial: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberSocialSecurityNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberGender: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberBirthDate: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphonenumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberworkphoneextensionnumber: string (nullable = false)
 |-- membercellphone: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memberAddresses: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lineOne: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lineTwo: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lineThree: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- cityName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- stateCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- zipCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- countyCode: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- countryCode: string (nullable = false)
 |-- memeberPhoneNumbers: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- phoneNumber: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- effectiveDate: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- terminationDate: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isCurrent: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isActive: null (nullable = true)
 |    |-- telecomType: string (nullable = false)
```

I have tried multiple different things to get it to work:

```scala
      ).as("clientAddresses"),
      array(
        struct(
```

```scala
      ).as("clientAddresses"),
       struct(
```

```scala
      ).as("clientAddresses"),
      array(
```

```scala
      ).as("clientAddresses"),
      collect_list(
        struct(
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the expected schema you want is not possible. I mean, when you have an array, it always contains an `element` with a given schema, which in your case is a struct. So I'd actually say that the schema you're getting is exactly what you want to achieve.